# Rotating a point around another point in 3D

Tags: c++, math, 3d, trigonometry

Can I figure out a point's 3D position after rotating the reference point it's relation to, by knowing:

- Point's world position (*vec3*)
- Point's offset from pivot point (*vec3*)
- The pivot's world position - Moving Pivot - Not At Center (*vec3*)
- The pivot's rotation on the 3 individual axis (*vec3*)

So ultimately, I'm not just trying to rotate a point around a pivot, but rather **rotate the pivot 3D point first (player), and based on it's rotation, I would like the other point rotate (orbit) around it**. The "other" point's position is not the same as the pivot point's, it's away from it in 3D and it's position (for now) is "player position + offset"

If anyone with trigonometry knowledge can give me a hand with this I'd greatly appreciate it

[image]

Comment: I've done stuff like this in Unity 3D by making some game objects the child of other game objects, and making them rotate or whatever around their parent.  I know that this is possible to do, however I wouldn't be able to give you the transformation matrix stack to actually answer your question.

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm trying to achieve indeed, the parenting "effect". At the moment the point moves with the player but is always at a set distance in a set direction - meaning that when I rotate the player right, the point will be to it's left and so on - the point should move around the player when rotating it, so that it's always in front of it

Comment: You mean `T(pivot) * R(pivot) * T(offset)`?

Comment: Translate and rotate the system to the origin, rotate the point, then undo the original translation and rotation.

Comment: I got you, translate to origin, rotate then translate back - no that's not what I mean. I need to modify the position of the point so that it looks like its orbiting around the player when the player rotates. What you are saying would result in the point rotating around it's own origin rather than the player.

Comment: I'm thinking: I know the offset of the point from the player. I have a vector there, so would I be able to rotate that vector based on player rotation, then put the point to the end of the new vector? Is that possible? I don't even know how to rotate a vector in C++